# html - sending flash in email

Tags: html, flash, email, embed

I was wondering... in the past it was never smart to send flash in emails, but now it's 2011, and I thought, would it be smart to embed flash in emails, and even possible?

I wonder what you guys have to say about this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. You cannot embed binaries in emails. Attachments are another story.

Keep in mind: 40% of all mail users are on MS Outlook. Outlooks uses the brain-dead MS-WORD engine to render HTML. Imagine trying to embed FLASH in a Word doc. eek!

Comment: Haha, I kinda feared that... Do you know if there is a reason that Outlook still uses such a crappy engine?

Comment: Reason: It was probably easier to secure.

Comment: Too bad, 'cause it would also bring several improvements in visual design posibilities..